# Mouse Move event not working for me on Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I m working on project to play video. I used play/pause/stop buttons in panel and panel is disabled and not visible initially.

I want to enable it by mouse move event, but when I move cursor in panel contained area, it does not show me panel control, here is code..

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X >= top_left.X && e.X <= top_right.X && e.Y >= top_left.Y && e.Y <= bottom_left.Y)
         SetEnabled(true);
    else SetSenabled(false);

    void SetEnabled(bool enabled) => (panel1.Visible, panel1.Enabled) = (enabled, enabled);
}
```

What can I do now?

Comment: have you add pnlOne.MouseMove+=this.mouseeventhandler(pnlOne_MouseMove); to constructor?

Comment: where i can add such code

Comment: After InitiallizeComponent(); Beware!!: My code is not 100% correct. Follow the autocomplete.

Comment: If the control is not visible or enabled how do you expect to get messages?

Comment: I just cant believe it how it is possible.. can you give me code for Mouse Enter event to perform above action...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An invisible panel won't throw any events, so the only way to really do this is with a timer and check whether or not the mouse is inside the control's area or not:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Rectangle r = pnlOne.RectangleToScreen(pnlOne.ClientRectangle);
  if (r.Contains(MousePosition)) {
    if (!pnlOne.Visible)
      pnlOne.Visible = true;
  } else {
    if (pnlOne.Visible)
      pnlOne.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

No need to change the panel's Enabled property (just leave it `Enabled=true;`) since you seem to only care to show the panel when the mouse is in the control's area.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while, but I'm fairly sure that if a control has .Enabled set to false, it won't respond to any event handlers. What benefit do you get from the panel being disabled? You should enable it and try then. As Poomrokc The 3years said, make sure the method is tied to the control as the event handler. You don't need to add it programmatically though. You can set it manually in the designer (not recommended) or select the panel and in the Properties panel, go to the event handlers and assign it that way.

Comment: Maybe you should try using the MouseOver instead of MouseMove?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X >= pnlOne.Location.X && e.X <= pnlOne.Location.X + pnlOne.Size.Width && pnlOne.Visible == false && e.Y >= pnlOne.Location.Y && e.Y <= pnlOne.Location.Y + pnlOne.Size.Height)
    {
        pnlOne.Visible = true;
        pnlOne.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void pnlOne_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlOne.Visible = false ;
    pnlOne.Enabled = false ;
}
```

Comment: still not working... give me your email address then i will send you my hole code

Comment: @user3540132 Post it here. If it is too long upload it somewhere to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The enable property is set to false!

Whatever object the mouse event is being used must have the enable property set TRUE!